# awk replace field value based on matching value in another file

Tags: awk

I have 2 files, `Zipcode.txt` and `Address.csv`:

```
ZipCode.txt
12345
23456
34567
45678

Address.csv
12345,3587 main st,apt j1,city,new jersey
23456,4215 1st st. s.,suite a2,city,new jersey
65432,115 main st,,city,new jersey
45678,654 2nd st n.,city,new jersey
```

If the zipcode field in `Zipcode.txt` matches the zipcode field in `Address.csv`, I want to change the 4th field from `city` to `found`. Here's what I want:

```
12345,3587 main st,apt j1,found,new jersey
23456,4215 1st st. s.,suite a2,found,new jersey
65432,115 main st,,city,new jersey
45678,654 2nd st n.,found,new jersey
```

This is what I have tried:

```
awk -F',' 'BEGIN{OFS=FS}NR==FNR{a[$1]=1;next}a[$1]{$4="found"}1' Address.csv ZipCode.txt
```

Comment: Do you want to search for any zip code in the file or only on the corresponding line (first line in the first file must match the first line in the second file)?

Comment: The zip code can be on any line of the file, not always the first line.

Comment: Very well, then see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will search whether the zip code in the first field of `Address.csv` is found anywhere in `Zipcode.txt`:

```
awk -F, -v OFS="," 'NR==FNR {a[$1]++;next} $1 in a {$4="found"} 1' Zipcode.txt Address.csv
```

Output:

```
12345,3587 main st,apt j1,found,new jersey
23456,4215 1st st. s.,suite a2,found,new jersey
65432,115 main st,,city,new jersey
45678,654 2nd st n.,city,found
```

Note that the last line is not as expected, because `city` is not the fourth field in the input: a comma is likely missing in the last line of `Address.csv`.

Comment: simlev, when I ran you command:

Comment: I got it to work thanks, can I ask another question on this same thing or should I start a new question?

Comment: @bullet117 You should always ask a new question, just add a link to this question if they are related.