# AWK, replace field value by matching fields in two files

Tags: awk

I have 2 files Address.csv and ZipCode.txt, I want to generate a file that is similar to the Address.csv and update the city field from "city" to "found" when the Zipcode matches the first 5 characters of the Zip in the Address.csv file.

What I have:

```
  Address.csv
  Zip,Address1,Address2,conty,city,state
  65432-3421,115 main st,atlantic,city,new jersey
  45678-4098,654 2nd st n.,bergin,city,new jersey
  23456-3425,4215 1st st. s.,suite a2,camden,city,new jersey
  12345-6278,3587 main st,apt j1,essex,city,new jersey

  ZipCode.txt
  23456
  12345
  34567
  45678
```

What I want:

```
  NewAddress.csv
  Zip,Address1,Address2,conty,city,state
  65432-3421,115 main st,atlantic,city,new jersey
  45678-4098,654 2nd st n.,bergin,found,new jersey
  23456-3425,4215 1st st. s.,suite a2,camden,found,new jersey
  12345-6278,3587 main st,apt j1,essex,found,new jersey
```

What I have tried with the help of Simlev [awk replace field value based on matching value in another file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/522679/awk-replace-field-value-based-on-matching-value-in-another-file):

```
  awk -F, -v OFS="," 'NR==FNR {a[$1]++;next} $1 in a {$4="found"} 1' ZipCode.txt Address.csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing that has to be changed in your script is to get the first 5 characters of the first field using function `substr`.

The data in `Address.csv` is inconsistent. The first two data lines have 5 fields, the others have 6 fields. That's why I use `$(NF-1)` (next-to-last field) instead of `$4` (4th field). Otherwise wrong fields get changed with your example data.

```
awk -F, -v OFS="," 'NR==FNR {a[$1]++;next} substr($1,1,5) in a {$(NF-1)="found"} 1' ZipCode.txt Address.csv
```

This prints

```
Zip,Address1,Address2,conty,city,state
65432-3421,115 main st,atlantic,city,new jersey
45678-4098,654 2nd st n.,bergin,found,new jersey
23456-3425,4215 1st st. s.,suite a2,camden,found,new jersey
12345-6278,3587 main st,apt j1,essex,found,new jersey
```